# why my round function doesn't work well in sas

Tags: sas, rounding

my code is

```
data ex1;
set ex1;
if count in (1,2,3,4) then do;var1=round(var,0.1);end;
run;
```

After round I have,

```
var1
9.3
8.8
2
5.8
3
```

As you can see I have no 1 decimal in the whole column , could someone assist me why ? Thank you !

Comment: You want to have 1 decimal no matter the remainder, correct?

Comment: no ,in the others I want 2 decimals , but in those that have count 1,2,3,4 i want 1, thank you

Comment: If you are wanting conditionally a different number of decimal places displayed when the values are viewed (i.e. rendered), you will need to store that rendering in a character variable (i.e. conditionally `var1=put(var,BEST8.1); else var1=put(var,BEST8.2)` .  Formats don't change the underlying value but control how the value is rendered in output.

Comment: thank you but doesn't work in my dataset as well. Could you please share with me the code with the round?

Comment: Your example data does not show the value of COUNT.  What value to you want to assign to VAR1 when COUNT has some other value?  Note that all 5 numbers you show in the output have been rounded to the 10ths decimal place.  It is just that for 2 of them the the result were integers.

Comment: If you want to use the round function depending on the row number you have to use "\_N\_" instead of "count". In SAS, "count" will here be just another column, if it does not exist SAS will create it with nothing else but missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the 8.1 Format like below

```
data want;
input var1;
format var1 8.1;
datalines;
9.3 
8.8 
2   
5.8 
3   
;
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but i don't want the whole variable with the same format , for this reason i have wrote the count . could you help me ?